# Поменять местами разъемы

Tags: linux, аудио, ubuntu

Разъем для наушников сломался, есть еще для микрофона, но им я не пользуюсь.

Можно ли их программно поменять местами на ubuntu?

Comment: Google в помощь: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu

Comment: @void можно ли услышать ответ на русском. думаю не только мне поможет

Comment: [Читайте][1]


  [1]: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.omgubuntu.co.uk%2F2013%2F12%2Fturn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu&edit-text=

Comment: @void как будто я сам не пробовал. ну да ладно спс

Comment: @M11 Ну если пробовали, что там ведь так и написано в переводе, что необходимо скачать программку. Ну а для всего остального существует http://bit.ly/1xxJSFS. Я просто почему это упоминаю: если вы пытались искать и знаете о чем речь, то в вопросе хотя бы модель компа упомянули бы (если ноутбук) или хоть модель звуковой карты, так как от этого зависит, возможно ли программно переназначить. Потому что, если "железно" привязано, то никакая программа или драйвер не помогут. Вот почему.

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться программой [hdajackretask](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu) из пакета [alsa-tools-gui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alsa-tools-gui&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).